# Smart pointer which can change ownership at runtime (C++)

Tags: c++, destructor, smart-pointers, ownership

I often encounter a situation when I have complex class (e.g. implementing some numerical algorithm like Partial Differential Equation Solver) with data arrays which it can **either own or bind from external context** depending on use case. The problem is how to make robust destructor for such class. Simple way is to make boolean flag which indicates wheather the array is owned.  E.g.

```
// simplest example I can think about
class Solver{
   int     nParticles;
   bool own_position;
   bool own_velocity;
   double* position;
   double* velocity;
   // there is more buffers like this, not just position and velocity, but e.g. mass, force, pressure etc. each of which can be either owned or binded externally independently of each other, therefore if there is 6 buffers, there is 2^6 variants of owership (e.g. of construction/destruction) 
   void move(double dt){ for(int i=0; i<n; i++){ position[i]+=velocity[i]*dt; } }

   ~Solver(){
       if(own_position) delete [] position;
       if(own_velocity) delete [] velocity;  
    }
};
```

Naturally, this motivates to make a template wrapper around the array pointer (should I call it smart pointer ?):

```
template<typename T>
struct Data{
   bool own;
   T* data;
   ~Data{ if(own)delete [] T; }
}; 


class Solver{
   int          nParticles;
   Data<double> position;
   Data<double> velocity;
   void move(double dt){ for(int i=0; i<n; i++){ position.data[i]+=velocity.data[i]*dt; } }
   // default destructor is just fine (?)
};
```

**Question:**

- This must be common pattern, do I reinvent a wheel here?
- Is something like this in C++ standard library ? (sorry, I'm rather a physicist than a programmer)
- are there some catches to think about ?

### ----------------------------------------

**EDIT:** To make clear what `bind to external contex` mean (as Albjenow suggested):

**case 1) private/internal work array (no shared ownership)**

```
// constructor to allocate own data
Data::Data(int n){
    data = new double[n];
    own  = true;
}

Solver::Solver(int n_){
    n=n_;
    position(n); // type Data<double>
    velocity(n);
}

void flowFieldFunction(int n, double* position, double* velocity ){
   for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
      velocity[i] = sin( position[i] );
   }
}

int main(){
   Solver solver(100000); // Solver allocates all arrays internally
   // --- run simulation
   // int niters=10;
   for(int i=0;i<niters;i++){
       flowFieldFunction(solver.n,solver.data.position,solver.data.velocity);
       solver.move(dt);
   }
}
```

**case 2) Bind To External data array (e.g. from other class)**

```
Data::bind(double* data_){
    data=data_;
    own=false;
}

// example of "other class" which owns data; we have no control of it
class FlowField{
   int n;
   double* position;
   void getVelocity(double* velocity){
      for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
         velocity[i] = sin( position[i] );
      }
   }
   FlowField(int n_){n=n_;position=new double[n];}
   ~FlowField(){delete [] position;}
}

int main(){
   FlowField field(100000);
   Solver    solver; // default constructor, no allocation
   // allocate some
   solver.n=field.n;
   solver.velocity(solver.n);
   // bind others 
   solver.position.bind( field.position );
   // --- run simulation
   // int niters=10;
   for(int i=0;i<niters;i++){
       field.getVelocity(solver.velocity);
       solver.move(dt);
   }
}
```

Comment: A `std::shared_ptr`?

Comment: You could technically use a `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr` with a custom deleter that stores whether to delete (you own it) or do nothing (externally owned). Writing your own class works too, but getting it right in every aspect takes some experience...

Comment: ther is also boosts [intrusive_ptr](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/libs/smart_ptr/doc/html/smart_ptr.html#intrusive_ptr)

Comment: @MaxLanghof Custom deleter would be an overcomplication here. You can either `get()` the managed raw pointer, or construct `weak` out of it.

Comment: It is very unclear, how you would transfer ownership. In particular it is very unclear how other instances of the pointer are informed, when the owner gets destructed. Everyone else would have a dangling pointer, if they don't get informed. If there is no particular reason, why shared ownership is a problem, I suggest that you go for `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: I read specification of https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr already several times, and I don't know. It seems to complex, and therefore I expect it can have also some memory and runtime overhead, as well as to introduce some limitations and unconveniences.

Comment: Can you give an example of "bind from external context". Without knowing your usecase(s), it's hard for us to suggest a solution.

Comment: UniversE > "other instances" does not have to know. If the data array is owned `own=True` than the arraoy should not be accessed from outside at all (or if it is it is responsibility of user to handle that issue). This is not the task here. The task here is to make class which can either allocate its own working array, or bind to already existing work array.

Comment: Albjenow > Aha, you are right, perhaps I should make this more clear

Comment: @ProkopHapala Use an `@` to reply to people, that way they will be notified of your reply. (Somewhat confusingly, people commenting on your question will automatically notify you without doing that).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple way to do what you want without having to write any smart pointer yourself (it would be hard to get the fine details correct) or writing a custom destructor (which would mean more code and bug potential from the other special member functions required by the [rule of five](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)):

```
#include <memory>

template<typename T>
class DataHolder
{
public:
    DataHolder(T* externallyOwned)
      : _ownedData(nullptr)
      , _data(externallyOwned)
    {
    }

    DataHolder(std::size_t allocSize)
      : _ownedData(new T[allocSize])
      , _data(_ownedData.get())
    {
    }

    T* get() // could add a const overload
    {
        return _data;
    }

private:
    // Order of these two is important for the second constructor!
    std::unique_ptr<T[]> _ownedData;
    T* _data;
};
```

https://godbolt.org/z/T4cgyy

The `unique_ptr` member holds the self-allocated data, or is empty when externally owned data is used. The raw pointer points to the `unique_ptr` contents in the former case, or the external content in the latter case. You could modify the constructors (or only make them accessible via static member functions like `DataHolder::fromExternal()` and `DataHolder::allocateSelf()` which return `DataHolder` instances created with the appropriate constructor) to make accidental misuse harder.

(Note that the members are initialized in the order they are declared in the class, not in the order of the member initializer lists, so having the `unique_ptr` before the raw pointer is important!)

And of course, this class cannot be copied (due to the `unique_ptr` member) but can be move-constructed or -assigned (with the correct semantics). Works out of the box as it should.

Comment: Thanks, I get what you mean. But I'm not sure if I like this. Because it adds some complexity (it is like wrapper of a wrapper). If there would be instant canned solution in standard library I would probably use it. But when I have to write my own wraper, I prefer to do it from scratch, because I don't like using something I don't know what excatly it does, how it is implemented (the `unique_ptr`). It may be inefficient for the specific use case (do some unnecessary work, and use unnecessary memory), and I have no control over that. Sorry, maybe I too old fashin C-person.

Comment: There is no canned solution, and this is probably the lowest amount of complexity you could add (short of side-stepping the entire problem as suggested in the other answer). If you don't understand what this wrapper does, feel free to ask. There is nothing magic here, everything should be quite clear given basic knowledge of modern C++. This solution uses virtually no extra space and performs no extra work - you end up working with the raw `T*` like before.

Comment: I understand what the wrapper you wrote does. I don't know how exatctly the `unique_ptr` is implemented (guess it is platform dependent). To me all smart pointers are wrappers of raw pointers. So writing wrapper of smart pointer is writing wrapper of wrapper. From sentence like *make accidental misuse harder* I think you think in different context. I'm not trying user from doing something. I'm trying to make class which is most flexible to use with minimum boilerplate. add "rule of five" - ok, perhaps I will hit a wall at some point, but I never had to follow that.

Comment: And I warmly recommend getting accustomed with `std::unique_ptr` so that you can alleviate your fears of space or performance overhead (it has neither). All it does is 1. express (on a semantic level) that you uniquely own a resource and 2. take care of releasing that resource on destruction. That's it. Just that it's a wrapper doesn't mean it's slower or bigger or any such thing. Look at the generated assembly if you don't believe me.

Comment: Good to know. In that case, you are right. I'm thinking about getting accustomed with smart pointers already for some time. But uncertainity about their implemplementation, and lanck of use case where I would really need them (or find them convenient) always detered me. Just aestetically, and ergonomically I like `*` much more than `std::unique_ptr<>` as it is much shorter (less visual noise in the code).

Comment: That's fair. Yes, smart pointers are more noisy than `*` - but in most cases, a reader of the code will find that the conveyed information of "I own this thing and will clean it up" is definitely worth that visual bandwidth ;)

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to separate data ownership from your solver algorithm. Having the algorithm optionally manage lifetime of its inputs isn't good design because it leads to entanglement of separate concerns. The solver algorithm should always refer to already existing data. And have another extra class that owns data, if necessary, and have lifetime no shorter than that of the algorithm, e.g.:

```
struct Solver {
    int nParticles;
    double* position;
    double* velocity;
};

struct Data {
    std::vector<double> position, velocity; // Alternatively, std::unique_ptr<double[]>.

    template<class T>
    static T* get(int size, std::vector<T>& own_data, T* external_data) {
        if(external_data)
            return external_data;
        own_data.resize(size);
        return own_data.data();
    }

    double* get_position(int nParticles, double* external_position) { return get(nParticles, position, external_position); }
    double* get_velocity(int nParticles, double* external_velocity) { return get(nParticles, velocity, external_velocity); }
};

struct SolverAndData {
    Data data;
    Solver solver;

    SolverAndData(int nParticles, double* external_position, double* external_velocity)
        : solver{
              nParticles,
              data.get_position(nParticles, external_position),
              data.get_velocity(nParticles, external_velocity)
          }
    {}

    SolverAndData(SolverAndData const&) = delete;
    SolverAndData& operator=(SolverAndData const&) = delete;
};

int main() {
    SolverAndData a(1, nullptr, nullptr);

    double position = 0;
    SolverAndData b(1, &position, nullptr);

    double velocity = 0;
    SolverAndData c(1, nullptr, &velocity);

    SolverAndData d(1, &position, &velocity);
}
```

Comment: ok, but that needs unnecessary boilerplate, and poluting namespace

Comment: @ProkopHapala Added an example for you. I don't think _unnecessary boilerplate, and poluting namespace_ apply here at all.

Comment: What about constructor and destructor which automatically handle all variations the cases when all the work buffers (there is many more than just `position` and `velocity`) can be either own or binded externally? If there is 6 such buffers, I would need 2^6 different wrappers? Not to say that I wrote in the title, I prefer to to switch the ownership runtime.

Comment: @ProkopHapala `SolverAndData` owns inputs in the example. When no ownership of inputs is required just use `Solver` alone.

Comment: yes, but it owns all the data, or you assume there is just one data buffer. But In the situations I encounter there are many different cases (all combintations). E.g. sometimes the particles have some variable mass (each different), sometimes there are weight coefficients etc. and I don't want to make specific class for each such case. That is why I think most efficient solution is to enable switching ownership at runtime, and make constructor which handle all 2^6 ways of initialization depending on the arguments. Naturally I don't want to complicate the intial question with that.

Comment: @ProkopHapala Added another example for you.

Comment: Hi, thanks, make sense. But i still like more my approach, because I can define my data wraper `template<typename T>struct Data{bool own;T* data;~Data{ if(own)delete [] T; }}; ` only once, and reuse it for every new solver. While in your case that bolilerplate should be reimplemented for every solver from scratch.

Comment: @ProkopHapala One normally has `DataAccess` whose sole purpose to manage data for you.

Comment: Not sure what exactly you mean by `DataAccess`. But I general I feel like speaking with software engineers about good practices is not always applicable to my situation. You perhaps assume lot of human resources, and the bottleneck is organization of collaboration. I have little human resources (just me), and I need to express lot of functionality with little code. I use C++ (over C) for expressiveness and performance, not for safety. I'm happy to use something which makes something automatically for me so I don't have to care. But not at the cost of expresiveness.